# Converting onClick methods over to tap methods in Zepto

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, webkit, zepto

Is there a simple to re-write links on a mobile web-app from onclick to tap using Zepto? Currently I want to fire the $.tap command for every instance of onclick.

For example

```
<a href="#" tap="doSomething(); return false;">Link</a>
```

Is this possible, or is there a way to prevent the onclick from firing, but take the onclick method and call it inside the $.tap method?

Any suggestions for making fast buttons using Zepto?

Comment: something like when you tap .trigger('onclick')

Comment: Yes - but how can you prevent the onclick from firing when clicked?

Comment: do you mean is there a way to disable it from going to the link? or is there an onclick function somewhere that you do not want to trigger?

Comment: I mean that i dont want the onclick to fire on click, i want to to fire the onclick function on "tap" via zepto.

Comment: so basically the onclick function function will run when you tap right? they both do the same thing except one is when you click and the other is when you tap correct? so when you tap the screen, trigger the onclick function since they do the same thing. now if you dont want it to go to the link then just return false on the anchor click.

Comment: Any acceptable answer so far ?

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant way would be to store your click trigger in a variable and then remap that variable from "click" to "touchstart" when you're dealing with a touchscreen device.

Here, I use a global object variable, myUtils, to store my click event, which defaults to "click" as its value:

```
var myUtils = myUtils || {};
myUtils.events = myUtils.events || {
  click : "click"
};
```

If there's a touchscreen detected, then I change my myUtils.events.click property to have a value of "touchstart":

```
if (typeof document.body.ontouchstart !== "undefined") {
  myUtils.events.click = "touchstart";
}
```

Now, when I'm binding my click events to my elements, I use my myUtils.events.click property for name of the event:

```
$(function() {
   $("#link").bind(myUtils.events.click, function(e) {
     alert("I'm a " + e.type);
     e.preventDefault();
   });
});​
```

This way I only have to do the "is it a touchscreen?" test once in my application and I will bind to either "touchstart" or "click" as needed thereafter.  I don't have to worry about cancelling the unwanted click event on a mobile device, since that event is never bound in the first place.

The e.preventDefault() call will prevent the link from being followed (assuming #link is an href link).

JSFiddle version: http://jsfiddle.net/BrownieBoy/Vsakw/

Be warned that this code assumes that a touchscreen device is *only* a touchscreen device; i.e. a phone or a tablet.  If you're on a touchscreen PC then you won't be able to use it with a mouse!

Answer (score 0):

ok so the way i understand you is you want different behaviors on mobile and desktop but with the same code. If so then you need to identify which platform you are on then define your code

```
if(MOBILE) {
    $('element').click(function(){
        return false;
    });

    $('element').on('touchstart', function(){
        // functionality of the onclick written here
    });
}
else {
// desktop event listeners
}
```

Comment: Right - but I have hash fragements that need to be fired, such as <a href="#_pageOne">Page One</a> - and I still want that to alter the URL. Will the return false make that url change invalid?

Comment: Please avoid `live`... use `on` instead.